# In scraping, can't login with Mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, web-scraping, mechanize

My aim: On ROR 3, get a PDF file from a site which requires you to login before you can download it

My method:

- Step 1: log in to the site with Mechanize
- Step 2: since I'm logged in, get the PDF with Nokogiri

Apparently, the login didn't succeed because I get nothing when I debug (pretty sure that the nokogiri part works well, already tested)

Below my code:

**My Controller.rb**

```
begin

# login to the scraped site:
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get("http://elwatan.com/sso/inscription/inscription_payant.php")

#look for the wanted form
form = puts agent.page.parser.css('form')[1]

#login
agent.page.forms[1]["login"] = "my_login"
agent.page.forms[1]["password"] = "my_password"
agent.page.forms[1].submit


#scrape with nokogiri
docwatan = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.elwatan.com/'))
@watan = {}
docwatan.xpath('//th/a').each do |link|
@watan[link.text.strip] = link['href']
end
```

**My View.rb**

```
<ul id= "list">  
<% if @watan %>
<% @watan.each do |key, value| %>
<li class="List" ><a href="http://www.elwatan.com/<%= "#{value}" %>" target='_blank'>      <%= "#{key}" %></a></li><% end %>
<% end %>
```

**and the login form, from the scraped site**

```
<form method="post" action="/sso/login.php" id="form-login-page">
<div id="form-login-container-page" style="color:red;text-    align:center;width:100%;margin:10px 0"></div> 
<input type="hidden" name="minimalist" value="1"><input type="hidden"    name="SSO_Context" value=""><div class="clear"> </div>
<label>Email<span>*</span></label>
<div class="insc-saisie">
<input class="insc-saisie-champ" type="text" id="login-page" name="login" value="">
</div>
<div class="clear"> </div>

<label>Mot de passe<span>*</span></label>
<div class="insc-saisie">
<input class="insc-saisie-champ" type="password" id="password-page" name="password"    value="">
</div>
<div class="clear"> </div>

<label><input type="checkbox" unchecked=""></label>
<div class="insc-saisie">Se souvenir</div>
<div class="clear"> </div>

<label> </label>
<div class="insc-saisie">
<a href="javascript:showLostPassForm();">Mot de passe oublié ?</a>
</div>
<div class="clear"> </div>

<label> </label>
<div class="insc-saisie">
<input class="b-connexion" type="image" src="/img/trans.gif">
</div>
<div class="clear"> </div>
<div class="clear"> </div>
<label><span>*</span></label>
<div class="insc-saisie">Saisie obligatoire</div>
<div class="clear"> </div>
</form>
```

kinhdly notice that the login is done on this page  "http://elwatan.com/sso/inscription/inscription_payant.php", and the download from "http://elwatan.com"; could be important

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
docwatan = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.elwatan.com/'))
```

You want to do:

```
docwatan = agent.get('http://www.elwatan.com/')
```

otherwise the session cookie isn't getting sent in the request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! problem is, right now, the nokogiri part isn't working, I don't get anythig when I debug; any solution ? thanks a lot

Comment: Try dumping page.body and make sure the html looks the way you expect.